# C++ .NET Construct control from HWND

Tags: .net, winapi, c++-cli, hwnd

Is it possible to construct a .NET control from an HWND? For example:

```
HWND mHwnd; //ListView handler
ListView^ lv = gcnew ListView(mHwnd);
```

Or just a method that gets the control by an HWND:

```
HWND mHwnd;
ListView^ lv;
lv = ListView::GetControlByHandle(mHwnd);
```

If none of the examples are feasible, maybe a reference could work? Obtaining a kind of identifier to the element.

Those are just examples, I've already searched but found nothing related. Is there something that approaches to what I need? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't C++. What language are you really using?

Comment: @IInspectable It is C++/CLI. I'm using Visual Studio.

Comment: Is this your ultimate goal? Or do you have some other motivation?

Comment: There's nothing like that in the framework. Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271659).